# MS Access: How to select entries by month using query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I make a database for theatre tickets selling system. There are tables with theatres, spectacles and sessions of spectacles (one spectacle can be showed many times). In table with sessions there is a date field. I need to make a form, where user can choose a theatre and a month, and will get a report with a list of sessions in chosen theatre for chosen month. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please post an example of your data and code you have tried so far. Stackoverflow is here to offer assistance, but the community generally doesn't code things from scratch.

Comment: [Data scheme](http://s1.postimg.org/db5exjcf3/001_scheme.png"); 

[My form](http://s1.postimg.org/pbquy9jtr/001_form.png) with a list of theatres(takes data from table) and a list of monthes(i entered them myself)

[And a querry](http://s1.postimg.org/pbquy9jtr/001_form.png) 
I tried to use value of month list inside Month() function, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you are searching for the Month Function.So when you select a month you need to perform this on the query :

```
WHERE Month(DateOfSession) = " & me.cboSelectMonth
```